# How to calculate time zone UTC offset for specified date and time with NodaTime (given daylight)?

Tags: c#, nodatime

I have Iana time zone Id and need to know the time zone offset for some DateTime.
As I understand, the following function returns the offset for DateTime.Now (or no daylight offset?).

```
TimeSpan GetTimeZoneOffset(string timeZoneId) =>
    new DateTimeZoneCache(TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default)
        .GetZoneOrNull(timeZoneId)
        .GetUtcOffset(SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant())
        .ToTimeSpan();
```

But I need

```
TimeSpan GetTimeZoneOffset(string timeZoneId, DateTime utcInstant)
```

How to implement it?

Comment: A *date* doesn't have an offset - a specific instant in time does. A single date could span multiple offsets, due to (for example) daylight saving time transitions. Please clarify the question.

Comment: Okay, so "for some DateTime" is a little more reasonable - is that always a `DateTime` with a `Kind` of UTC? Your example answer assumes so, but it's really important. (What if it's a `Kind` of Unspecified, and that value is skipped or ambiguous?

Comment: As a more meta note, Noda Time provides the most value when you use it throughout your code base - I'd recommend staying within the context of Noda Time (so `Instant` and `Offset` rather than `DateTime` and `TimeSpan`) for as much of the code as possible. Only convert to BCL types at the boundaries of your code, if you need to for compatibility.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I am trying to find a solution to my problem with very small experience in Node Time. To do that I google using terminology that is already known to me and the knowledge that I already have. There is good to use correct terms in an article, but in SO question, it is better to keep the question as is (to simplify googling for people who will have the same problem). If something is wrong in my question it can be corrected in an answer and can be pointed to me that I don't understand something.

Comment: Well, I really don't want to add an answer until the assumptions in the question are clarified - mostly what `Kind` of `DateTime` you need to be able to handle. Will it only ever be UTC?

Comment: @JonSkeet In my case, instant is in UTC, and I checked that when `Kind != Utc` I have an exception.

Comment: Right - I'm aware that it would throw an exception, but it's not clear from your question whether that's all you *need* it to do. It would be good to clarify your requirements in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, you need [`DateTimeZone.GetUtcOffset`](https://nodatime.org/3.0.x/api/NodaTime.DateTimeZone.html#NodaTime_DateTimeZone_GetUtcOffset_NodaTime_Instant_), which accepts an `Instant`.

If the `DateTime` value always has a `Kind` of `Utc`, you can use [`Instant.FromDateTimeUtc`](https://nodatime.org/3.0.x/api/NodaTime.Instant.html#NodaTime_Instant_FromDateTimeUtc_System_DateTime_). If it might have a different `Kind`, you'll need to work out more detailed requirements.

Next you need an `IDateTimeZoneProvider` to map the time zone ID into a `DateTimeZone`. That might be `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb`, or it might be one you've injected somewhere for testability.

Once you've got the `Instant` and the `DateTimeZone`, you can call `GetUtcOffset` to get an `Offset`. You *can* convert that back to a `TimeSpan`, but I'd actually encourage you to avoid using `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` as far as possible in your app - if you can use the Noda Time types everywhere within your codebase and only convert between those and the BCL types at boundaries (e.g. database access) you'll find you need to do a lot less of this work.

But if you really need a `TimeSpan`, the method would look like this:

```cs
TimeSpan GetTimeZoneOffset(string timeZoneId, DateTime dateTimeUtc)
{
    Instant instant = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(dateTimeUtc);
    DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timeZoneId];
    Offset offset = zone.GetUtcOffset(instant);
    return offset.ToTimeSpan();
}
```

Note that the `IDateTimeZoneProvider[string]` indexer will throw an exception if the time zone isn't found in that provider. If you want to handle this a different way, use `IDateTimeZoneProvider.GetZoneOrNull()` and check whether the result is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan GetTimeZoneOffset(string timeZoneId, DateTime date) =>
    new DateTimeZoneCache(TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default)
        .GetZoneOrNull(timeZoneId)
        .GetUtcOffset(Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(utcDay))
        .ToTimeSpan();
```

Comment: I would recommend using `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb` rather than creating a new `DateTimeZoneCache` each time - and this will throw a `NullReferenceException` if the zone ID is unknown. If you want to fail with an exception, just use the indexer - that will throw a much clearer exception.

Comment: @JonSkeet In my real-world project, I have DateTimeZoneCache as a singleton injection. Also, I sure that timeZoneId is correct because it was validated in an earlier stage of data flow. Anyway indexer using is a good point.